# UIViewControllerWrapperView backgroudColor question

Tags: ios

VC1 present a nav（it conatins VC2） which is translucent, when i use VC2 push new VC3,and than back from VC3,the VC2 change to opaque. why?

my purpose is still translucent.

Answer (score 0):

I found the UIViewControllerWrapperView's backgroundColor change from clear color to whrite color

Comment: You can do it programmatically in viewWillAppear, viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidAppear (etc)

Comment: I find the UIViewControllerWrapperView, and change backgroundColor to clearColor, but not work